# Pesquisar registro em duas tabelas com nodejs e mysql

Tags: node.js

Estou usando o `NodeJS` e `Mysql` e preciso mostrar no meu formulário a listagem das postagens. Essas eu busco na tabela "postagens", porém no item categoria, aparece o id da categoria. Como eu busco o nome da categoria na tabela "categorias" na mesma consulta? Segue o código:

```
router.get('/postagens', (req, res) => {
    Postagem.findAll({order:[['id', 'desc']]}).then((postagens) => {
        res.render("admin/postagens", {postagens: postagens})
    }).catch((err) => {
        req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao listar as postagens")
        res.redirect("/admin")
    })
  });
```

Em Models: postagem.js

```
const db = require('./db')

const Post = db.sequelize.define('postagens', {
    titulo: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    slug: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING
    },
    descricao: {
        type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
    },
    conteudo: {
        type: db.Sequelize.TEXT
    },

    categoria: {
        type: db.Sequelize.STRING,
   allowNull: false,
  references: {        
      models: 'categorias',
         key: 'id',
    },
  },
})

module.exports = Post


Em Admin.js

//Postagens 
//Listando as postagens
router.get('/postagens', (req, res) => {
     Postagem.findAll({order:[['id', 'desc']]}).then((postagens) => {


         res.render("admin/postagens", {postagens: postagens})
     }).catch((err) => {
         req.flash("error_msg", "Houve um erro ao listar as postagens")
         res.redirect("/admin")
     })
})


postagens.handlebars

<h2>Lista de Postagens</h2>
<hr>
<a href="/admin/postagens/add"><button class="btn btn-success">Nova postagem</button></a>


{{#each postagens}}
  <div class="card mt-4">
      <div class="card-body">
          <h4>{{titulo}}</h4>
          <p>Descrição: {{descricao}}</p>
          <small>Data de criação: {{#formatDate dataValues.createdAt}}{{/formatDate}}</small></p>
          <small>Categoria: {{categoria}}</small><br>
          <a href="/admin/postagens/edit/{{dataValues.id}}"><button class="btn btn-success mt-3">Editar postagem</button></a>
          <br>
          <a href="/admin/postagens/deletar/{{dataValues.id}}"><button class="btn btn-danger mt-4">Deletar postagem</button></a>
      </div>
  </div>
{{else}}
  <p><h4 class="mt-3">Nenhuma postagem registrada!</h4></p>
{{/each}}
```

Minha pergunta é bem simples: Qual a instrução em mysql, que substitui essa no nodejs?

```
Postagem.findAll().populate("categorias").sort({data:"desc"}).then((postagens) => {
```

Comment: Adicione na pergunta o código do objeto `Postagem`

Comment: use o populate do mongoose https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/query.html#query_Query-populate

Comment: Obrigado Teuuz1994, mas estou desenvolvendo com mysql. Preciso da instrução em Mysql. Obrigado.